# changing view transition animation style on ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I use ionic framework for my hybrid mobile app. Default , page transition is slide from left to right for android. I want to cahnge this effect. For example I want to make this effect as slide upto top. How can I change view transition effect on ionic?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible to change the transitions. You can only disable and change the direction... But you can try to change the transition animations with [native transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-transitions) plugin

Regards
Mert

Comment: How can you make only change the direction?

Comment: @AGoranov like this:
$ionicNativeTransitionsProvider.setDefaultTransition({
        type: 'slide',
        direction: 'left'
    });

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 new transition effects in addition to ususal Slide: Fade, Cube and Coverflow

example:
mySlideOptions = {
      autoplay: 2000,
      speed:1000,
      effect: 'Coverflow',
  };

Comment: which one does the `up to down` transition?